# Is it possible to run python-crontab on a remote server?

Tags: python, cron, remote-server

I have gone through all of the documentation, cant seem to find an answer or example of using python-crontab to run a cronjob on a remote server. Is this possible?

Link to the library: https://github.com/doctormo/python-crontab

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest looking at the excellent [fabric](http://www.fabfile.org/) library for dealing with remote servers.

The fabtools library provides some cron functionality for fabric http://fabtools.readthedocs.io/en/0.19.0/. Here's an example from that page

```
from fabtools.cron import add_task

# Run every month
add_task('cleanup', '@monthly', 'alice', '/home/alice/bin/cleanup.sh')

# Run every tuesday and friday at 5:30am
add_task('reindex', '30 5 * * 2,4', 'bob', '/home/bob/bin/reindex.sh')
```

Comment: Although this isnt a direct answer for my question I appreciate the suggestion. I'll probably end up using this. Marking answer as correct